# Why doesn't my submit button hide?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**Background:** I have a form on a single page with several div's that start out with only the first div showing and all others hidden.  As you make a selection, the next form div is dynamically built and displayed based on the choices in the previous div.  All previous form divs are still displayed.  You progressively end up with more of the form fields showing as you progress through the choices.  I have not put the whole code up here for brevity.

I am using JavaScript for this.  I am NOT using jQuery intentionally as I am still working on being completely comfortable in JavaScript before I start relying on a library.

**My Problem:** I want to hide the submit button at the end of the form until the last form div is revealed.  Everything I am trying is not working and I've exhausted things I have found on the web.  It should be really simple, but apparently their must be something special about a submit button that is not in my JavaScript knowledge yet.

**What I've Done:** Below is what I think should work, but does not (I have kept the code limited to the issue at hand, however if someone thinks it is deeper then this I will happily edit and add more code).  The onclick() function is working properly for otherDiv.  i.e. when you click on the 2nd to last Div, OtherDiv is displayed as expected.  It should also reveal the submit button, but does not (and the submit button is not hidden in the first place).

The problem is as simple as for whatever reason, the submit button is not given the style of "none" on page load and also is not give the style of "block" when the onclick() event happens.

I see in my console the below error that shows when I use GetElemntsByName to target the submit button as shown below, but am not sure why I am getting it.  I understand the error, just not why my targeting of the submit button with GetElementsByName is throwing the error.

I have also tried this targeting the submit button by Id with GetElementById and while the console error below goes away then, I still do not get the submit button hidden.

I have shown the code below with the GetElementsByName error because I want to understand that error as well as solving my hidden submit button problem.

**Console**

```
TypeError: pdfButton.style is undefined
if(pdfButton) {pdfButton.style.display = 'none'};
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="buildShopDrawing" name="BuildShopDrawing" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="buildPDf" id="buildPDf" class="buildPDFbutton" value="Build the Shop Drawings PDF">    
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function preparePage() {

        // Set common divs to var for ease of use
        var pdfButton = document.getElementsByName('buildPDF');

      // hide: submit button until last form is revealed    
      for (var i = 0; i < door.length; i++) {
        door[i].onclick = function() {
          if(this.checked) {
            otherDiv.style.display = 'block';
            pdfButton.style.display = 'block';
          }
        };
     };

      //hide form divs on initial page load
     if(pdfButton) {pdfButton.style.display = 'none'};

    } //end preparepage

// Do not execute JavaScript until page is loaded
window.onload =  function() {
preparePage();
};
```

As always, your help is appreciated!

Comment: General tip: Use classes, not direct styling. doesn't really matter for such a small page/site though. One source of the failing code might be that `getElements...` returns an array-like list of elements. Thus, you need to access `.style` on an index in that list, not on the list itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That makes sense on the Console Error.  One problem down, now to solve why when I use GetElementByID it still does not hide the submit button

Comment: If you haven't already, add trace statements to your js so you can verify that appropriate functions are running, use dev tools in chrome/firefox to inspect DOM and see if classes are applied, and use the style insepctor to see if there is a css error, such as conflicting styles and your style being overwritten. 

Thats the best I can do at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. `id="buildPDf"` != `('buildPDF')`

(And as others pointed out, use `getElementById`)

Comment: As stated above, "I have also tried this targeting the submit button by Id with GetElementById and while the console error below goes away then, I still do not get the submit button hidden."

Comment: I believe single quotes and double quotes are the same in Javascript and and using double quotes for HTML does not impact the selection.  Nonetheless, I did change the ('buildPDF') to ("buildPDF") in the javascript and it made no difference.

Comment: I meant the lowercase / uppercase f, not the quotes.

Comment: Oh for crying out... You rock!  You know how many times I have confirmed that ID and Name field?  Its always the most obvious, stupid typo isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use document.getElementById instead of getElementsByName that return a collection, it mean you can access element by its index only.

Comment: As stated above, "I have also tried this targeting the submit button by Id with GetElementById and while the console error below goes away then, I still do not get the submit button hidden."